# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class servlets.LoginServlet

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jsp, servlets

So I am working on an assignment for school and this error is happening and I don't know how to fix it. I don't think it's a coding error, just a project setup error.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried the other answers I've found online such as "Project Clean..." etc and nothing works.

EDIT 1/

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class servlets.LoginServlet
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlets.LoginServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I can't seem to post the web.xml on here...
http://hastebin.com/sadikezece.xml

LoginServlet.java

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import beans.UserBean;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet implements Serializable {



/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public LoginServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    UserBean user = new UserBean();
    user.setUsername(request.getParameter("username"));
    user.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

}

Didn't do anything to it because it wasn't running.

Comment: 500 means a coding problem. Please post your web.xml, you are getting a class not found exception, which means that web container is not able to locate the servlet.

Comment: @Sean please share web.xml and servlet code

Comment: Do not post screenshots of text. Copy/paste the stack trace into your post and format as code (use the `{}` button in the editor).

Comment: @JimGarrison Added the output in {}, XML wasn't working.

Comment: @JayPrakashKumar I added the XML code.

Comment: its looking like hello.LoginServelet Not there so please shase Servlet code

Comment: @JayPrakashKumar I did share the LoginServlet code. The screenshot shows hello.LoginServlet because I made another package named hello to test and see if something else would work, sorry my screenshot is inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a Maven web-app and it didn't seem to work so I made another project as a "Dynamic Web App" and it worked beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Please look careful about schema version of web.xml and use of tags like:

```
<description></description>
<display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
```

And also check package name in web.xml Or   Please change your web.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>servlets.SearchServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/search</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Comment: This didn't help. :/

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason. First I can see a red cross on your project. It means your project will not be compiled again before you solve the issue. But you cannot see any err in your code.
Then you can choose window/show view/other , then choose problems. You can see the tab about err and waring next the console.